# $.on() performs multiple times. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I discovered a strange thing in my code:

```
drawing.activeObjects = new Array();
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("clicked" + $(this).attr('id'));
    drawing.activeObjects.push(findOBJInArray($(this).attr('id')));
    console.log("aO: " + JSON.stringify(drawing.activeObjects));
});
```

When I click on my object one time, everything is ok. But when I click again it runs two times. And after my seven clicks, I can see 7 times "clicked" in console and seven objects in array.

I really don't know why. I have one object on my site, and I clear my array before I check for clicks. But yet I see as many objects in array as the number of clicks I make.

Comment: Either you are calling the code that is adding the on() multiple times or you have nested elements with the same class.

Comment: is that script coming from ajax request ?

Comment: The `.on()` is also better be written like that: `$("div").on("mousedown", ".svgobjects", function(){` assuming those are `<div>` elements with that class.

Comment: Show more context. Where is this snippet located? How is it called?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not necessarily. It depends.

Comment: But that's absolutely normal. If you click seven times it is ok to have seven elements inside your array and severn "clicked" logs. That's because you are executing the handler of the event seven times.

Comment: @JasonP on what? I always wondered about it and so far didn't find any "solid" documentation. As far as I can tell, such thing: `$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){` is exactly the same as `$(".svgobjects").bind("mousedown", function(){` - isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mainly I think on 1) whether the elements or selection criteria are dynamic, and 2) how many elements are being targeted by the handler.

Comment: based on your updated question description, it sounds like the click handler is doing exactly what it should.  every time you click it writes "clicked".  When you click the first time you see it once, when you click the second time, do you see it a total of two times in the console or three copies of the word "clicked"?

Answer (score 0):

The code does not magically know you only want to listen for one click on the element and no more. You need to program it so it behaves that way.

If you only expect it to be called one time, than you need to remove the code for the click or you can look at jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)